# Handling large http response using boost::beast

Tags: c++, http, boost, beast

The following code use to get http response message:

```
  boost::beast::tcp_stream stream_;

  boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
  boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::dynamic_body> res;
  boost::beast::http::read(stream_, buffer, res);
```

However, In some cases, based on the preceding request, I can expect that the response message body will include large binary file.

Therefore, I’d like to read it directly to the filesystem and not through `buffer` variable to avoid excessive use of process memory. How can it be done ?

in Objective-c framework `NSUrlSession` there's an easy way to do it using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` instead of `NSURLSessionDataTask`, so I wonder if it's also exist in boost.

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can use the [`http::buffer_body`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_http/parser_stream_operations/incremental_read.html) to handle arbitrarily large request/response messages.

If you specifically want to read/write from a filesystem file, you can have the `http::file_body` instead.

### Full Demo `buffer_body`

The documentation sample for `buffer_body` is here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_http/parser_stream_operations/incremental_read.html.

Using it to write to std::cout: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dc099823130fcdb)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace net       = boost::asio;
namespace beast     = boost::beast;
namespace http      = beast::http;
using tcp           = net::ip::tcp;
using socket_t      = tcp::socket;

/*  This function reads a message using a fixed size buffer to hold
    portions of the body, and prints the body contents to a `std::ostream`.
*/

template<
    bool isRequest,
    class SyncReadStream,
    class DynamicBuffer>
void
read_and_print_body(
    std::ostream& os,
    SyncReadStream& stream,
    DynamicBuffer& buffer,
    beast::error_code& ec)
{
    http::parser<isRequest, http::buffer_body> p;
    http::read_header(stream, buffer, p, ec);
    if(ec)
        return;
    while(! p.is_done())
    {
        char buf[512];
        p.get().body().data = buf;
        p.get().body().size = sizeof(buf);
        http::read(stream, buffer, p, ec);
        if(ec == http::error::need_buffer)
            ec = {};
        if(ec)
            return;
        os.write(buf, sizeof(buf) - p.get().body().size);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string host = "173.203.57.63"; // COLIRU 20210901
    auto const port  = "80";

    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::resolver   resolver{ioc};

    socket_t s{ioc};
    net::connect(s, resolver.resolve(host, port));

    write(s, http::request<http::empty_body>{http::verb::get, "/", 11});

    beast::error_code  ec;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;

    read_and_print_body<false>(std::cout, s, buf, ec);
}
```

### Full `file_body` example

This is much shorter, writing to `body.html`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b6be7759d066725)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace net       = boost::asio;
namespace beast     = boost::beast;
namespace http      = beast::http;
using tcp           = net::ip::tcp;
using socket_t      = tcp::socket;

int main() {
    std::string host = "173.203.57.63"; // COLIRU 20210901
    auto const port  = "80";

    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::resolver   resolver{ioc};

    socket_t s{ioc};
    net::connect(s, resolver.resolve(host, port));

    write(s, http::request<http::empty_body>{http::verb::get, "/", 11});

    beast::error_code  ec;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    http::response<http::file_body> res;
    res.body().open("body.html", beast::file_mode::write_new, ec);
    if (!ec.failed())
    {
        read(s, buf, res, ec);
    }

    std::cout << "Wrote 'body.html' (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Headers " << res.base() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Wrote 'body.html' (Success)
Headers HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8616
Server: WEBrick/1.4.2 (Ruby/2.5.1/2018-03-29) OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Date: Wed, 01 Sep 2021 19:52:20 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

With `file body.html; wc body.html` showing:

```
body.html: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines
 185  644 8616 body.html
```

### Beyond: streaming to child processes and streaming processing

I have an advanced example of that here: [How to read data from Internet using muli-threading with connecting only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787334/how-to-read-data-from-internet-using-muli-threading-with-connecting-only-once/61809655#61809655).

Comment: Thanks, that's working perfectly. I just wish there also an option to automatically direct the response to file without user interaction.

Comment: You're actually right. I forgot aout `file_body`, mentally assuming it was only for serializing bodies from static files. I rewrote a [simple example of buffer_body to ostream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dc099823130fcdb) to use [file_body instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b6be7759d066725) and it's much easier indeed. Adding that to the answer text.

Comment: Much updated the answer. Thanks for making me notice my mistaken assumption  :) I simply forgot I had seen that in the source code once in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, for some reason, after i use the `file_mode` method, it somehow disconnected the socket, so i had to reconnect in order to re-use it. I haven't encountered such behavior when working with the chunk-base technic... Perhaps do you know why ?

Comment: That's normal HTTP behaviour with `Connection: close` headers (assumed if absent). The alternative requires Content-Length and/or chunked encoding to be used (so you don't treat eof as end of response)